# No veo las db creadas en PhpMyAdmin

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqlconnector

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos mediante python usando mysql.connector. La base de datos se crea con éxito segun despliego en consola. Mi código es el siguiente:
import mysql.connector

```
# conexion
database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='*******',
)
cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE PROGRAMASDB')


cursor.execute('SHOW DATABASES')

for db in cursor:
    print(db)
```

Hasta acá todo bien, de hecho en consola, veo la base de datos que acabo de crear llamada 'PROGRAMASDB':

```
('information_schema',)
('mysql',)
('PABLODB',)
('performance_schema',)
('PROGRAMASDB',)
('python_devDB',)
('sys',)
```

El inconveniente está en el momento en que intento ver la base de datos en phpmyadmin, no aparece ninguna de las bases de datos que acabo de crear:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente es como si no tuviera conexión con lo que yo estoy haciendo. En este momento estoy utilizando XAMMP 8.1.5.

Necesito poder ver las bases de datos que estoy creando en Python en phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar luego de desinstalar MySQL en mi Mac. Lo que sucedió fue que estaba trabajando con dos MySQL: la que estaba instalada y la que viene por defecto en XAMMP. Simplemente basó con desinstalar MySQL desde preferencias del sistema.