# MySQL da error Table doesnt exist in engine

Tags: mysql, xampp

Sé que este problema es muy típico y he buscado mucho en google y en foros para ver la solución. He encontrado varias soluciones, pero el problema es que ninguna funciona.
Todo iba bien hasta que ayer entré a xampp y me fijé que el puerto estaba bloqueado. Como esto ya me había pasado antes, realicé lo que hago siempre, que es seguir una solución que dio un usuario de mysql (esta solución consiste en copiar los archivos de data en otra carpeta y los de backup,les dejo el [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)). El caso es que cuando volví a entrar, todas las tablas estaban en uso. Fui a repararlas, y para mi sorpresa me sale el siguiente error:

> Table doesnt exist in engine.

Comment: ¿Te fijaste si tenés más de una instalación de MySQL? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @padaleiana Con más de una instalacion Mysql te refieres a los archivos dentro de data? Por cierto, gracias me lo leeré para saber más.

Comment: Se refiere a que tal vez tienes una instalación de MySQL aparte de la de XAMPP. Ese fue el problema en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/529955/281846)

Comment: Precisamente @Fedex7501.

Comment: @Fedex7501 Ahh. Vale. Nono. No tengo mysql instalado asi que solo tengo uno, el de xampp.

Comment: ¿Te fijaste qué servicio estaba usando ese puerto bloqueado?

Comment: @padaleiana La verdad no. Como ya me había pasado muchas veces, ni lo miré, fui a solucionarlo directamente.

Comment: @padaleiana Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Despues de pegar mil cosas y de borrar otras tantas (confieso que al azar) ha funcionado. He recuperado todas las tablas menos una. Gracias.

Comment: En ese caso, intenta ser descriptivo en tu respuesta (en base a [answer]), y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.